# Views 'Post-Login Landing Page' in Drupal

Tags: drupal, post, authentication, view

I plan on creating a custom post-login landing page in Drupal 7, preferably using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) or just custom PHP (anything dynamic).

This page will only be for admins. I want it to show:

- Welcome back {user}
- Blocks of data containing fields (filtered for active data only)
- Add/Edit/Manage Content Blocks (so they won't need to use Drupal toolbar as much)
- Other useful admin blocks

I have created a Views page called 'Welcome back' but not sure where to go next. Multiple blocks to sit inside the one page, or something along those lines.

Although, a custom PHP page is an option if the views method is not recommended (impractical).
I also have [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module but haven't learnt it too much at this stage.

Comment: And what is your question? You mainly gave a description what you did but you have not asked much.

Comment: @hakra: Tell my clients that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [dashboard](http://drupal.org/project/dashboard) module or [homebox](http://drupal.org/project/homebox). Pair that with [logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) to redirect users to the dashboard as soon as they log in and you have yourself a descent set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might give Homebox a try. Sorry for the late reply.